# Airflow using ExternalTaskSensor Operator caused MySQL innodb deadlock

Tags: python, mysql, airflow, innodb, airflow-scheduler

I use **ExternalTaskSensor** Operator in Airflow to manage dependencies between DAGs, My **ExternalTaskSensor** Operator code looks like this:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='sushi.batch.load.application.detail.1d',
    default_args=InitConf.getArgs(start_date=datetime(2021, 12, 9)),
    description='Load Application Detail Data',
    schedule_interval='00 */3 * * *',
    tags=['sushi', 'develop']
)

monitor_handleApplicationData = ExternalTaskSensor(
    task_id='wait_for_application_handle_end_detail',
    execution_date_fn=lambda dt: dt + timedelta(minutes=35),
    external_dag_id='sushi.batch.handle.application.1d',
    external_task_id='application_handle_end',
    timeout=7200,
    allowed_states=['success'],
    mode='reschedule',
    pork_interval=60,
    check_existence=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

The sensor running mode is [`reschedule`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.1.2/concepts/sensors.html), The Sensor takes up a worker slot only when it is checking, and sleeps for a set duration between checks.

But I found that Airflow scheduler crashed down because of MySQL Innodb deadlock sometime, so I had to restart the Airflow scheduler often. And here some log that I collect in Airflow scheduler docker container:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')
[SQL: UPDATE task_instance SET external_executor_id=%s WHERE task_instance.task_id = %s AND task_instance.dag_id = %s AND task_instance.execution_date = %s]
[parameters: (('2b14b7a2-46ef-4ec1-b16b-5f6b1f0610d2', 'wait_for_application_handle_end_detail', 'sushi.batch.load.application.detail.1d', datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 20, 0, 0)), ('4e878253-f0dd-4465-a0d1-39dbc444b882', 'wait_for_application_handle_end_dict', 'sushi.batch.application.dict.handle.1d', datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 20, 0, 0)), ('4bafb4a2-c614-41e0-bd1b-5c47dd5334aa', 'wait_for_application_handle_end_dict_test', 'sushi.batch.application.dict.handle.test.1d', datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 20, 0, 0)))]
```

It shows that there is one update sql caused deadlock, I call it **`SQL 1`**:

```
UPDATE task_instance SET external_executor_id='2b14b7a2-46ef-4ec1-b16b-5f6b1f0610d2'
       WHERE task_instance.task_id = 'wait_for_application_handle_end_detail'
       AND task_instance.dag_id = 'sushi.batch.load.application.detail.1d'
       AND task_instance.execution_date = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 20, 0, 0)
```

Here's the
[MySQL `task_instance` table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtQnr.jpg)

The primary keys are `task_id`, `dag_id`, `execution_date`. When update, innodb engine will lock rows which the condition of the `task_id` column is satisfied first, it's indeed possible to deadlock if two Task with same `task_id` in two different DAG. But my `dag_id` and `task_id` are both unique in all DAGs and Tasks, there's no reason caused deadlock. So I check the MySQL transaction log and I found another update sql, I call it **`SQL 2`**:

```
UPDATE task_instance SET state='scheduled' 
       WHERE task_instance.dag_id='sushi.batch.load.application.detail.1d'
       AND task_instance.execution_date='2022-05-20 00:00:00' 
       AND task_instance.task_id. IN ('wait_for_application_handle_end_detail')
```

I seems know why deadlock happened, **`SQL 1`** and **`SQL 2`** might execute in same time and the `task_id` are both `wait_for_application_handle_end_detail`. I know why **`SQL 2`** was executed, because my **ExternalTaskSensor** running mode is `reschedule` and poke interval is `60s`, it means that **`SQL 2`** will execute every 60 second to change the task current state. But I don't know why **`SQL 1`** was executed, what's `external_executor_id` used for?

I know change the running mode of **ExternalTaskSensor** to `poke` might solve this problem, but it will takes up a worker slot for its entire runtime. Is there any other solution besides this?

Answer (score 0):

Both of those Updates will run faster with this composite Index:

```
INDEX(dag_id, execution_date, task_id)
```

By being indexed and running faster, most (or maybe all) deadlocks will be prevented.

Even so, you should replay the query if it does encounter a deadlock.

Do you have any "transactions"?  (EG, with `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`?)